# Как воспроизвести IllegalStateException через ContentEncodingHttpClient?

Tags: java

У меня есть небольшая java-программа, которая получает данные с удаленного хоста раз в несколько секунд. Через несколько недель непрерывной работы, она начинает сбоить и вылетает эксепшн:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid use of BasicClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.

Код примерно такой:

```
HttpClient client = new ContentEncodingHttpClient();
HttpGet method = new HttpGet(url);
method.addHeader(contentType", applicationJson);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(method);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
Reader result = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent(), 
EntityUtils.getContentCharSet(entity));
```

В нем еще есть авторизация, но я ее убрал для простоты.

Кто знает, как можно воспроизвести это исключение? Хочу проверить исправленный код так, чтобы не ждать десяток дней, но как не пробую, получить ошибку не могу.

Comment: А запросы посылаются в один поток? `BasicClientConnManager` должен использоваться только одним потоком. В многопоточной среде нужны дополнительные приседания. См http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html "2.3.2. Simple connection manager", "2.3.3. Pooling connection manager", "2.4. Multithreaded request execution"

Comment: Бросьте его сами в той строке, на которой оно вылетает. Почему нет?

Comment: Поток один. Бросить эксепшн вручную не очень хорошо, т.к. мне надо убедиться, что следующий раз чтение пройдет успешно. А если ContentEncodingHttpClient не ламается, то и сама проверка по закрытию соединения и восстановлению связи будет не корректной.